# What is this property called? $\left.\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}\right|_{f(x)}=\frac{1}{df/dx|_a}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, but does anyone know what the property (see image attached) is called?

$$\left.\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}\right|_{f(x)}=\frac{1}{df/dx|_a}$$

[original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUCJ8.png)

There may be a mistake somewhere but I didn't even know how to begin searching for it on Google without a name. Thanks!

Comment: Google "inverse function theorem."

Comment: What I saw there was dy/dx = 1/dx/dy; that doesn't really seem to me, at least, to be the same thing. The verbal explanation I saw was "The derivative of the inverse function at a point equals the reciprocal of the derivative of the function at its inverse image point. " What's "a" in the image? Is the inverse function theorem the same as the verbal explanation?

Comment: I didn't really look at the image closely.  It seems to me that the derivative on the left is supposed to be evaluated at $f(a)$

Comment: So the image is saying that for the point (a, y), the derivative of the inverse at y is the same as 1 over the derivative of the original function at a?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Oh. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If $y=f(x)$, is one-to-one and onto (bijection) in domain $D$ so $x=f^{-1}(y)$ exists and let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a good point on the curve such that $y_0=f(x_0)$.
Then $$\left .\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=y_0}=\left .\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right|_{y=y_0}=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}.$$

Suppose $y=f(x)=x^5+x+1,$ it is bijection (1,3) and (2,35) are good points whereas $y=1,2,4,5,6,7,8,...,32,34,..$ cannot give a good point as we cannot find $x_0$ forthem by HAND.

$$\left .\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=3}=\frac{1}{6}, \left .\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=33}=\frac{1}{81}.$$

But we cannot find $$\left .\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=1,2,4,5.6,7,8,......32,34,...}= ?$$ cannot be found by HAND.

This interesting property does not have any name and it can be proved by noting that $$f^{-1}(f(x))=x.$$